# CakePHP 3.1 - missing helper error for plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created a plugin, but didnt baked it, that basicly has a helper which I want to use in the application. When running the index.php I get the following error:

> Fatal error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingHelperException] Helper class EasyuiHelper could not be found.
>
> ```
>  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Core\ObjectRegistry.php(91): Cake\View\HelperRegistry->_throwMissingClassError('Easyui', 'Easyui')
>  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(1001): Cake\Core\ObjectRegistry->load('Easyui.Easyui', Array)
>  #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\src\View\AppView.php(40): Cake\View\View->loadHelper('Easyui.Easyui')
>  #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php(335): App\View\AppView->initialize()
>  #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\ViewBuilder.php(350): Cake\View\View->__construct(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response), Object(Cake\Event\EventManager), Array)
>  #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\ViewVarsTrait.php(119): Cake\View\ViewBuilder->build(Array, Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response), Object(Cake\Event\EventManager))
>  #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_ in C:\xampp\htdocs\myKMG_3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 156
> ```

I followed this procedure to create the plugin:

1. I created the plugin structure described by the cookbook in: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins
2. I created the helper for the plugin in `plugins/Easyui/scr/View/Helper EasyuiHelper.php:`

   ```
   namespace Easyui\View\Helper;

   use Cake\View\Helper;

   class EasyuiHelper extends Helper {
       public function linkButton($id_image='imgLinkButton', $optionsImg=array()){
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. I added the following line in config/bootstrap :

   ```
   Plugin::load('Easyui');
   ```

   these in `View/AppView`:

   ```
   public function initialize()
   {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->loadHelper('Easyui.Easyui');
   }
   ```

   and this one in `Controller/AppController`:

   ```
   public $helpers = ['Easyui.Easyui'];
   ```
4. I use the helper in default layout file:

   ```
   $this->Easyui->linkButton('imgPrint', array('iconCls'=>'icon-print', 'onClick'=>'window.print()'));
   ```

Where did I go wrong?
Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the path to your composer.json so that the autoloader can pick them up. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Easyui\\": "./plugins/Easyui/src",
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Easyui\\Test\\": "./plugins/Easyui/tests",
    }
}
```

I recommend you to *always* read the *whole* chapter and not only partial excerpts of it. ;)

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I added this also.
(So I read the whole chapter, but thanks for the suggestion)

Comment: Did you rebuild the autoloader? composer dumpautoload? You can try to debug the autoloader and see what paths it attemps to call for that namespace - if it does so at all.

Comment: After, adding '['autoload' => true]'  to 'Plugin::load('Easyui');' it works.
(I recommend meself to always reread the chapter again and again ... )